# IE11 - Get a reference to a window (opened by another domain) by name

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, postmessage

I have the following problem:

- x.com is my parent page
- y.com is a child frame living inside x.com
- the frame has a button which calls `window.open('y.com/foo', 'MYWINDOWNAME')`
- y.com is then opened as a popup window

---

```
+------ x.com (parent) -------+
|                             |
|   +-- y.com (iframe) --+    |    +--- y.com (popup) ---+
|   |                    |    |    |                     |
|   |                    |    |    |                     |
|   |                    |    |    |                     |
|   |      [button]      |    |    |                     |
|   |                    |    |    |                     |
|   |                    |    |    |                     |
|   |                    |    |    |                     |
|   +--------------------+    |    +---------------------+
|                             |
+-----------------------------+
```

---

I need to find a way to get a reference to `y.com (popup)` from `x.com (parent)`. That's all I need -- a window reference -- obviously I'll have restricted access because the window is on a different domain, but I still need to get access to that reference.

In any other browser, I can just do `var mypopup = window.open('', 'MYWINDOWNAME');` but in IE I get an access denied error.

I've also tried sending a post message from `y.com (popup)` to `x.com (parent)`, and then using `event.source` to get a handle on the window, but in IE11 cross-domain post messages between window->popups are not supported.

Is there any other way of getting that window reference..?

Thanks!